# proving $|\lambda_1|<1<|\lambda_2|$.

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Let $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}(a+1+\rho \pm \sqrt{(a+1+\rho)^2-4a})$, where $a,\rho$ are complex numbers, $|a|=1, \rho\neq 0$. I want to prove the statement $|\lambda_1|<1<|\lambda_2|$. To do this I prove $(|\lambda_1|^2-1)(|\lambda_2|^2-1)<0$. After using parallelogram rule I am stuck at
$$|a^2|-\frac{1}{2}(|(a+1+\rho)^2|+|(a+1+\rho)^2-4a)|+1 <0.$$
Can anyone give a hint on how to continue? I also do not see why I need $|a|=1$.

Comment: edited to remove a few typos

Comment: Hint: $\require{cancel}\;\lambda_1\lambda_2=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\cancel{(a+1+\rho)^2}-(\cancel{(a+1+\rho)^2}-4a)\right) =a\,$, so $\,\left|\lambda_1\right| \cdot \left|\lambda_2\right|=\left|\lambda_1\lambda_2\right|=|a|=1\,$, then all that's left is to exclude the case $\,|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|=1\,$.

Comment: There is one case to be excluded, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by assuming that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$. For this to hold we must find some $a$ and $\rho$ with  $4a = (a+1+\rho)^2 = a^2 + 2(1 +\rho)a + (1 +\rho)^2$, which gives $a_{1,2} = -1 +\rho \pm \sqrt{(-1 +\rho)^2 - (1 +\rho)^2} = -1 +\rho \pm \sqrt{-4 \rho}$. Let $ i \sqrt \rho =q$ then $a_{1,2} = -1  - q^2 \pm 2 q = - (1 \pm q)^2$. However, since $q \neq 0$, this makes it impossible that $|a| =1$. Hence we have a contradiction, and  $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

Since $|\lambda_1||\lambda_2| =1$, as pointed out by @dxiv, there is one option to be considered (to be excluded) for  $|\lambda_1|<1<|\lambda_2|$ to hold, namely $|\lambda_1| = |\lambda_2| =1$ but 
$\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. This is the case if $\lambda_1 = e^{i \phi}$ and $\lambda_2 =  e^{i \psi}$ with $\phi \ne \psi$ (and no multiples of $2 \pi$). If we had that, then $a = e^{i (\phi + \psi)}$ and $\lambda^2 +a = (a+1+\rho) 
\lambda $ would give us, for $\lambda_1$: $e^{i 2 \phi} +e^{i (\phi + \psi)} = (e^{i (\phi + \psi)}+1+\rho) 
e^{i \phi} $ or 
$$
\rho = - e^{i (\phi + \psi)}-1 +e^{i  \phi} +e^{i  \psi}
$$
which is the same   for $\lambda_2$. 
Checking again with the orginal equation we obtain 
$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}(a+1+\rho \pm \sqrt{(a+1+\rho)^2-4a})\\
= \frac{1}{2}(e^{i  \phi} +e^{i  \psi}\pm \sqrt{(e^{i  \phi} +e^{i  \psi})^2-4e^{i (\phi + \psi)}})\\
= \frac{1}{2}(e^{i  \phi} +e^{i  \psi}\pm {(e^{i  \phi} -e^{i  \psi})})
$$
So this is indeed correct, and **this case has to be excluded in the task decription.**

Here is my earlier solution that, when excluding the case $|\lambda_1|= |\lambda_2|$, we have $|\lambda_1|<1<|\lambda_2|$:

$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}(a+1+\rho \pm \sqrt{(a+1+\rho)^2-4a})$ are 
the two solutions of the quadratic equation $\lambda^2 +a = (a+1+\rho) 
\lambda $. The complex conjugate of this is ${\lambda^*}^2 +  a^*= 
(a^*+1+\rho^*) \lambda^* $.  Multiplying the two gives $|\lambda|^4 + |a|^2
+ 2 Re (a \lambda^2 )= |a+1+\rho|^2 |\lambda|^2  $. Let $|\lambda^2| = x$. We equivalently need to establish $x_1 <1< x_2$.

We have 
$$
x^2- |a+1+\rho|^2 x +1 =  - 2 Re (a \lambda^2 ) = - 2 |a||\lambda^2 |\cos \alpha = - 2 x\cos \alpha 
$$
,with $\alpha$ the angle between $a$ and $\lambda^2$ in the complex plane. This gives
$$
x^2+ (2 \cos \alpha -|a+1+\rho|^2) x +1 =  0
$$
which has the  solutions
$$
x_{1,2} = \frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha  \pm \sqrt{(\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha )^2 -1}
$$
for $x =|\lambda^2 |$ which is  real and positive.
Since it *does* have real solutions, we have  that $(\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha )^2> 1$, and since $x$ is positive, it follows that $\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha  > 1$.

Hence the larger solution is evidently $>1$, whereas for the smaller solution to be  $<1$ it is  required that 
$$
\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha  - \sqrt{(\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha )^2 -1} <1
$$
or
$$
(\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha -1)^2 <  {(\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha )^2 -1} 
$$
or
$$
-2(\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha) +1 <   -1 
$$
or
$$
\frac12|a+1+\rho|^2 - \cos \alpha >1
$$
but  we have already established that. This completes the proof. $\qquad \Box$

Comment: @dxiv I put the derivation in the main text. Indeed, there is one case to be excluded.